# Scrum tool for Product Backlog management

Tags: scrum, product-backlog

My team and I are very keen on doing Scrum "manual"-style (with paper and scissors). Though, we are struggling to find a tool to manage our backlog.

The main requirements are:

- To be able to print the backlog in cards to stick to the whiteboard
- To be able to assign backlog items to the releases manually

So far we have not found anything that matches these criteria. Suggestions?

Comment: What do you mean by your second point? Are you looking for a way to represent the assignment on a pin-up board or equivalent?

Comment: [Jira](http://www.atlassian.com/software/jira/) does both and quite a lot more.

Comment: to drag stories into compartments called Releases. We use Pivotaltracker, it does so automatically and always in a wrong way. We want to do it manually.

Comment: my boss hates Jira, so it would be very difficult to budge him into it

Comment: @Pomario - didn't realize I was supposed to know what your boss thinks about Jira.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We're using [Rally](http://www.rallydev.com/). Once the sprint is defined, cards get printed, put up on the board, and we have a feedback loop between the board & the online record. Everyone in the office can see the board, so anyone can know the sprint status.

Comment: +1 looks like solid software, but I dislike the UI. Their website looks nicer and more intuitive than their software.  JK

Comment: @DaveE: you wrote "Once the spring is defined" -- did you mean "sprint", or is "spring" the name of a feature in Rally?

Answer (score 0):

### Keep it simple - spreadsheets + mail merge

Wouldn't it be simpler to use Excel spreadsheets and print Word document using Mail-merge and putting in the source of your Excel. Put as many cards on your paper (letter/A4) as required and merge the stories into a printable document.

I've used Excel several times and it works. It's simple, you can also add row colouring based on statuses etc. And when it comes to shareable spreadsheets Google Docs works just as good.

Answer (score 0):

We use ClearQuest for managing backlogs and features.